# Show the functional $ x(t) \mapsto \int_0^1 \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 - a x \right] \, dt$ is minimized at a parabola

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Consider functions $x(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $x(0) = x(1) = 0$.  I would like to find a prove that the functional

$$ x(t) \mapsto \int_0^1 \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 - a x \right] \, dt$$

is minimized along the curve $x_0(t) = a t (1 - t)$.  Perhaps I could argue that $x(t) = x_0(t) + \epsilon \, x_1(t)$ and differentiate with respect to $\epsilon$ ?

This is not unlike the isoperimetric problem.

Comment: Have you written down the Eulier-Lagrange equation for the problem?

Comment: I should also say, "Yes, you could write $L(x) = $ your integral, and then ask what is $L(x + \epsilon y)$, arguing that if $x_0$ is a minimum for $L$, then $\epsilon \mapsto L(x + \epsilon y)$ must have a minimum at $\epsilon = 0$ for every $y$, and see what this tells you (using integration by parts, and your boundary conditions)." This amounts to deriving the E-L equation by hand. I'm surprised you've got no boundary conditions on $x'(0), y'(0)$, but maybe those aren't needed for some reason.

Comment: finally I did recibe  an upvote, which positively validates me… if you closed the OP, I will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the functional $\int_0^1\left(\frac{x'^2}{2}-ax\right)dt$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation you need to calculate
$$\frac{\partial{\cal L} }{\partial x}=-a,$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial{\cal L} }{\partial x'}=x'.$$
Then the equation is
$$x''+a=0$$
which upon integration you will get 
$$x(t)=-\frac{at^2}{2}+Bt+C$$
for some other constants $B,C$.